# igraph, how to get custom vertex shapes with parameters

Tags: r, igraph

I'm having a problem with custom vertex shapes in R and igraph. I can use the example below to define a custom shape function with parameters, but when I try to add multiple shapes with different params, they all take the params from the last shape added.

For example, the code below is from the igraph manual with an extra two lines. It will plot 7-ray stars, even though I'm telling plot to use "star", which has vertex.norays=3

Anyone see the problem?

```
library(igraph)

# all vertex shapes, minus "raster", that might not be available
shapes <- setdiff(shapes(), "")
g <- make_ring(length(shapes))
set.seed(42)
#################################################################
# generic star vertex shape, with a parameter for number of rays
mystar <- function(coords, v=NULL, params) {
   vertex.color <- params("vertex", "color")
   if (length(vertex.color) != 1 && !is.null(v)) {
      vertex.color <- vertex.color[v]
   }
   vertex.size  <- 1/200 * params("vertex", "size")
   if (length(vertex.size) != 1 && !is.null(v)) {
      vertex.size <- vertex.size[v]
   }
   norays <- params("vertex", "norays")
   if (length(norays) != 1 && !is.null(v)) {
      norays <- norays[v]
   }

   mapply(coords[,1], coords[,2], vertex.color, vertex.size, norays,
          FUN=function(x, y, bg, size, nor) {
             symbols(x=x, y=y, bg=bg,
                     stars=matrix(c(size,size/2), nrow=1, ncol=nor*2),
                     add=TRUE, inches=FALSE)
          })
}
# no clipping, edges will be below the vertices anyway
add_shape("star", clip=shape_noclip,
          plot=mystar, parameters=list(vertex.norays=3))
# I ADDED THIS ################################################
add_shape("star7", clip=shape_noclip,
          plot=mystar, parameters=list(vertex.norays=7))

plot(g, vertex.shape="star", vertex.color=rainbow(vcount(g)),
     vertex.size=seq(10,20,length=vcount(g)))
```

Comment: okay, have a look at `igraph.options()` - it seems as if `vertex.norays` gets set globally , so even if you try to use a previous/earlier shape that option is saved from the most recent, and so will affect shapes that were defined earlier that also  take that parameter.

Comment: you can add `vertex.norays=3`, parameter or whatever, as an argument to the `plot(...`, rather than creating new shapes with different parameters

Comment: Great thanks, adding vertex.norays=3 rather than a new shape was the solution